# Finding the inverse function

Tags: inverse-function

Let $X=\{3, 5, 7, 10\}$ and let $Y=\{\text{fish}, \text{lion}, \text{penguin}, \text{cow}\}$
Let $f$ be a function from $X$ to $Y$ defined by

$f(3)=$ lion,

$f(5)=$ cow,

$f(7)=$ fish,

$f(10)=$ penguin

The function $f$ is an inverse function. Calculate the inverses:

a) $f^{-1}$(fish)$=$

b) $f^{-1}$(lion)$=$

c) $f^{-1}$(penguin)$=$

d) $f^{-1}$(cow)$=$

Whaaaaaat. I understand nothing. Please advise!

Comment: Draw two sets $X$ and $Y$ and connect each member to correspond member. $f$ is correct direction and $f^{-1}$ is it's inverse.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f$ is an inverse function. Calculate the inverses:

a) $f^{-1}(\text{fish})= 7$

b) $f^{-1}(\text{lion})= 3$

c) $f^{-1}(\text{penguin})= 10$

d) $f^{-1}(\text{cow})= 5$

In general, the inverse function sends values from the codomain (in this case $Y$) to the domain (in this case $X$).

Comment: But of course. I panicked then I read about all the fish and lions. Thank you!

Comment: @IdiotNerd No problem!